# Runtime overhead of blocks for immediate assignment of varible

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, objective-c-blocks

i like the structure of this code.

```
NSString *source = ^{
    switch ([picker sourceType]) {
        case UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera:
            return @"camera";
        case UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary:
        case UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum:
            return @"library";
    }
}();
```

it forces the compiler to throw an error if you add a new case to an enum and forget about it here.
this code wouldn't

```
NSString *source = nil;
switch ([picker sourceType]) {
    case UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera:
        source = @"camera";
        break;
    case UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary:
    case UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum:
        source = @"library";
        break;
}
```

i don't know how costly the block approach is.
¿anyone know the overhead of this?

Comment: You can get the 2nd block of code to cause a compiler warning by turning on the "Check Switch Statements" warning option under the Build Settings. Of course this affects all `switch` statements in your code which you might not want.

Comment: Why would the first form thrown an error for a missed case?

Comment: @Avi Due to no `return` statement being reached.

Comment: You might get a warning to that effect, but not an error, unless you specifically change the setting to treat this as such.  And there's already a warning for switch statements that can be enabled, so I don't see what the block version gives you.  I'd think the assignment block would be a better choice and give the same characteristics.

Comment: The warning is okay, but I'd prefer a hard error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is badly broken. You seem to be confused between Swift and Objective-C. Your problem is that you forgot break statements in the second code. Don't compare unbroken code with broken code. Fix the second example, then check whether it really doesn't give you an error if you add an enum value.

Comment: This is the right answer, if you don't implement either all possible values of the enum, or the `default` case the compiler will throw a warning, which makes the block unnecessary.

Comment: I forgot to put in the `break` statements, just a mistake in transcription. Not the heart of the question. Updated